# HTMLescaping + passing on special characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am trying to properly store the following string, which is the synopsis from https://play.google.com/store/tv/show?id=lXH-sW6govE:

```
>>> s='''&quot;Work Out New York&quot; invites viewers to break a sweat
         with some of New York City’s hottest personal trainers...'''

>>> import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(s)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The following string needs to be un-escaped for such things as `&quot;`, but it shouldn't try an interpret things such as the apostrophe, which it effectively re-encodes that.

How would I properly unencode and store the following string?

Comment: That apostrophe looks suspiciously like a microsoft "smart" quote, which is  some nonsense codepoint definitely outside of the ASCII range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roippi pointed out, you have a smart quote in your HTML, which is breaking `HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(s)`. You need to pass `HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(s)` a Unicode not an str.

If your HTML was baked into your script, then you could just set your encoding to UTF-8 in your editor and create a Unicode instead:

```
# coding=utf-8
s = u'''&quot;Work Out New York&quot; invites viewers to break a sweat
         with some of New York City’s hottest personal trainers...'''
```

With `# coding=utf-8`, Python will automatically decode your string for you to a Unicode.

As you're pulling this from a remote source, you should decode to a Unicode using the appropriate encoding. Either by checking the "Content-type" header for the encoding or by using Requests HTTP library, which does this for you and gives you a Unicode from `Request.text`

You may also want to consider BeautifulSoup, which will help you navigate the HTML DOM and unescape where necessary. Again, BeautifulSoup benefits from decoded Unicode input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, which works:

```
def unescape(self, s):
    p = htmllib.HTMLParser(None)
    p.save_bgn()
    p.feed(s)
    return p.save_end()
```

Using the normal HTMLParser.HTMLParser() does not. Reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml.